# How to assign type to string input as object to push

Tags: javascript, typescript, ember.js

I have a forEach that takes in a string and pushes an object. How would I type this appropriately?

```
const descriptionText: string = this.args.post.description || '';
const descriptionParts: string[] = descriptionText.split(/\s+/g);
let parsedDescriptionParts: object[] = [];

descriptionParts.forEach((text: string) => {
    let parts = {
       text,
       isLink: false
    }
    if (text.match('^(#|@)')) {
       parts = {
          text: `<span class=${this.boldClass}>${text}</span>`,
          isLink: true
       };
    }
    parsedDescriptionParts.pushObject(parts);
});

return parsedDescriptionParts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that a forEach never has an output.

This is the definition of `forEach` in `lib.es5.d.ts`

```
forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
```

So maybe your type is : `(string) => void`

Answer (score 0):

```
let descriptionParts: string[] = ['hello', '#goodbye']                                                                                     
let boldClass: string = 'abc'

let parsedDescriptionParts: object[] = descriptionParts
  .map(text => text.match('^(#|@)')
    ? { text: `<span class=${boldClass}>${text}</span>`, isLink: true }
    : { text, isLink: false }
  )

console.log(parsedDescriptionParts)
```

Comment: While I like the simplicity, this contains no typescript and excludes the other parts of the description that are not prefixed with @ or #.